# Rails Mercury authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, administration, helper, mercury-editor

I have set up mercury in my application. It works properly but since I'm still very new to rails I can't set up authentication. This is what I tried after run:
**rails generate mercury:install:authentication**

- It seems I can use the module in lib directory

  ```
  module Mercury
    module Authentication

       def can_edit?
         true if :authenticate_admin!  //(from device)
       end
    end
  end
  ```

And I tried to use this method in the view but it doesn't work.
Lib directory should be autoloaded since that row is not commented in config file.

By the way, just **adding a before_filter on the update method**, I prevent normal users form confirming edited pages. But they can still see the editor itself if they **modify the Url manually** which is unwanted.

- I tried to override Mercury Controller but it doesn't even work

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to define "it doesn't work". Are you getting errors, a stack trace, some logic error?

Comment: I can't prevent users from seeing the editor. So I'm not using the authentication of Mercury properly.

Answer (score 5):

Late answer I know but if it helps anyone else.

lib/mercury/authentication.rb

```
module Mercury
  module Authentication

    def can_edit?
      if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?
        true
      else 
        redirect_to root_path
      end
   end

 end
end
```

applicationcontroller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery
   include Mercury::Authentication
 ....
```

restart your server and then only the admin can see and update the page

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to explicitly include whichever module handles into authentication.rb like so:

```
module Mercury
    module Authentication
        include YourAppName::YourAuthenticationModule
        def can_edit?
            admin_signed_in?
        end
    end
end
```

Insert your module and authentication method accordingly and restart the server